# qTip input fields validation not working with display:none

Tags: jquery, validation, qtip

So basically I have a qTip that appears on mouseover, and the contents are in a div with dislay:none. I have validation on the input fields in that container, but they do not work with display:none. If you make it display:block it works outside the qTip.

Here are the fiddles with display:block & display:none:
http://jsfiddle.net/qdwZN/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/qdwZN/1/ 
I'm trying to make it work with the second fiddle, display:none. Any idea on how to get this thing working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having qTip2 and validate work toghether seems no to be an easy task. One thing you are doing wrong is this line:

```
 content: $('.hiddenForm').html(),
```

which should be (otherwise you make a copy of the html, while it should be a refernece)

```
 content: $('.hiddenForm'),
```

In this way something works, but there are problems in showing the error messages. For that, you should check this [post](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-post-ajax-from-qtip2-validation-form) (hope it helps).

Look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/qdwZN/4/

If you press the submit, nothing happens, then if you focus on one of the fields and press "TAB" you see a part of the error message

Comment: It seems to be impossible to get the form to be fully functional in the qTip. I can't understand why it can't be easy to accomplish. The post didn't have a solid answer either :(

Comment: the problem is that you must set the error message to display inside the qtip, but i don't think that is going to be easy, unfortunately

Comment: Why do you think the submit button does not work, only the focus?